# Excel chart property

Tags: excel, charts, jasper-reports, ireport

I have several charts in my report. I need to put the chart *as an image*.

This property can be achieved by selecting
 *Format Picture-->Properties--> "Don't move or size with cell"* in *MS Excel 2010*.

Can I achieve the design like at this image with *iReport*?
[image].

The current design:
[image]

Comment: @alexK any hints on how to do it?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, this is not possible.

Comment: thanks @GenericJon for replying. I did it by placing static text  element around it . although i didn't get the feature that i actually needed but i got the looks same.Thanks